# How does require in node.js deal with globals?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, require

I just found out that if I require a module and store it as a global, I can overwrite methods and properties in the module as shown below:

```
global.passwordhelper_mock = require("helpers/password")
sinon.stub(passwordhelper_mock, "checkPassword").returns true
```

If I then require another module which in itself utilizes the above stubbed method, my stubbed version will be used.

How does the `require` function in node.js take notice to these globals?  Why does it only work when I overwrite/stub a module that has been saved as a global?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How does the require function in node.js take notice to these globals?

Somewhere inside the module there must be a call to module.exports.someObject = function(x) {...} in order for someObject to be come available globally.

> Why does it only work when I overwrite/stub a module that has been saved as a global?

Not sure I follow here. If the object was hidden then you couldn't overwrite it. You can overwrite any object available to you, either a global object (e.g. console) or a property of any object available to you at runtime (e.g. console.log).

Comment: Well, if I do `passwordhelper_mock = require("helpers/password")`, the later on sutbbed mock will not be used. Doing `global.passwordhelper_mock` will however allow me to modify properties